# How do I use the Find function with a variable term, for example Run1, Run2, RunX

Tags: vba, excel, loops, variables

```
Cells.Find(What:="Run:1", After:=Cells(1, 1), _
 LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
 SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
 MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

This is the code that I want to use, but I would like to loop it to find Run:1, Run:2, Run:3... Etc..., Is there a way to add a variable in a reference to find `"Run:X"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a variable, and just concatenate it. Use something like this:

```
Dim counter as long
counter = 1
Cells.Find(What:="Run:" & counter, After:=Cells(1, 1), _ ...yaddayadda
```

Or use it in a loop:

```
For i=1 to 100
 Cells.Find(What:="Run:" & i, After:=Cells(1, 1), _ ...yaddayadda
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And the progress continues :) I couldnt thank the community here on stack overflow enough!